# How can I transfer all the audio from a linux to Win or OS X over the network with simple steps?

Tags: windows, macos, ubuntu, networking, audio

It seems like there are questions like this, but not answered. Maybe it is possible to answer it now ! So I would like to do the following: transfer all the sounds from a Ubuntu machine over my home network to my Windows7 PC or MAC OS X in simple steps, without spending days to reading manuals. So, simple steps please ! I dont need any difficult feature or whatever, just a simple audio forward through my network!

Comment: Transfer sound files, or real-time streaming?

Comment: real time streaming. I want to hear everything that come from that Ubuntu machine in my PC or MAC.

Comment: I can't give you and simple steps but pulseaudio can send all the sounds coming from your ubuntu machine over a network to another machine. It is easier if the second machine is running ubuntu but it should be possible with windows too.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the game, but if you're looking for a manual way to do it without buying software you can run an auxiliary cord from your ubuntu machines headphone jack to your Windows microphone jack. Then go to your Sound Settings by right clicking the speaker icon in the bottom right and go to Recording Devices. From there you can right click your mic input device and under the Listen tab select the box that says "Listen to this device.". It takes some playing around with the audio levels and you might need to download a better audio mixer in Ubuntu, but it does work. I'm not even going to mention any of the software solutions because the one I paid for that was supposed to be "the best" had lag over a Gigabit Ethernet connection. The better solution is a set of speakers and 2 headphone splitters.